# Management Studio "Import CSV" vs sqlcmd many INSERTs

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have this table:

```
Members(person_id, school_id)
```

In a local database in a local SQL Server

I have a file `inserts.sql` with 5.000.000 inserts:

```
Insert into Members(person_id, school_id) VALUES (...)
Insert into Members(person_id, school_id) VALUES (...)
Insert into Members(person_id, school_id) VALUES (...)
```

`inserts.sql` was created programmatically from `members.csv`

I tried 3 things: A, B, C

- A) I tried running the .sql in Management Studio but it throw an error because of not enough memory
- B)
  I tried running this file from MSDOS like this:

  ```
  sqlcmd -S localhost -d mydb -i inserts.sql
  ```

And my CPU got frozen from intensive work. I waited like 10 minutes and decided to ctrl+C. I had to restart the computer because it was all laggy and I could bearly move the cursor

- C)
  I went to SQL Management Studio and right clicked my **db > Tasks > Import data**

This opened a wizard and I followed this steps:

**from flat file > members.csv > sql client > to table members > finish**

This didn't put my cpu laggy at all and it finished in like 8 minutes. It also showed me a progress bar.

**Question: how come?
What is this wizard doing internally to achieve this? Isn't this wizard doing inserts? How is he achieving this speed and how is he achieving to put data into a table if not doing inserts?**

Comment: the wizard can insert rows in bulk into a new empty table without indexes or keys instead of inserting each row individually checking constraints each time

Comment: so it would be equivalent if I disabled all constraints manually and executed the .sql ? Makes sense. Of course disabling all constraints manually sucks and that is why the wizard is a good tool

Comment: it's not that you disable all constraints, import the data, and then leave it alone, you disable all constraints, import the data, and then recreate the constraints so they're only checked once by the server instead of incrementally each time another row is added.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard method C) actually creates a SSIS package behind the scenes. You can even save the package in order to rerun or edit it.
SSIS has many performance advantages, and is my preferred goto technology for data movement/integration.